# Unwanted View Dismissal After Segue

Tags: swift, segue, unwind-segue

I'm trying to perform dismissal of modal ViewController and after that automatically move to the next ViewController. I use for this unwind segue and performSegue inside unwind.

```
@IBAction func unwindWithChatTo(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatStartTwo", sender: nil)
}
```

**The problem**: is that after performSegue executed and the next ViewController appears, unwanted segue back to the first view is performed.

**The flow:** Modаl View -> 1VC -> 2VC -> 1VC (Unwanted)

**What could be the reason of this unwanted segue back and how to fix this?**

I haven't found any advice on such cases. Much appreciate you advice.

Comment: What class is the `unwindWithChatTo` method in?  The unwind method needs to be in the presenting controller, not the modal controller.  You also can only unwind to that controller, not to a different one (afaicr).  I'd look at using the dismiss method with a completion block that initiates the luanch of the next VC.

Comment: Thank you! I finally decided not to use unwind here and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check if 2VC has any segue defined(performed) in the storyboard or programmatically.  Try putting a breakpoint in **`viewDidLoad` or `viewWillApear` of 1VC** or *`viewWillDisAppear` of 2VC* and try to trace back the trigger point for displaying 1VC again.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried you suggestions, but didn't found the rootcause. Finally decided to make this logic without unwind segue and this issue didn't appear.